# Getting empty response from Ads Insights API when no impressions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get Facebook performance metrics for my marketing account.

My account had no impression prior to today. When I make a call to get performance data for today (by setting *date_preset* parameter to *today* I get response with data. But when I do a call to get yesterday's data (when I had no impressions), I get empty response:

```
{'data': []}
```

This is not very helpful. I'd like to get response with impressions = 0. How can I do that?

I do the call to the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/ACCOUNT_ID/insights?level=ad&fields=impressions&&date_preset=yesterday&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible, as Facebook only returns data if there is data to return. What you can do is provide a callback to the response that checks if data exists for a certain day, and if not, populate that day with zeros.